# Nginx reverse proxy for Jersey SSE, CLOSE_WAIT connections eventually choke server

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I have a java webapp that uses Jersey SSE, when I directly connect to my tomcat instance, the no: of CLOSE_WAIT connections does not grow.(verified this with cURL)

When I go through the nginx reverse proxy, connections related to the SSE call keep growing (in CLOSE_WAIT) and finally the server process chokes, and needs a restart. Given below is my config, I am guessing that nginx closes the connection every 60s and then creates a new one for the next SSE request, any ideas how to fix this ?

```
upstream tomcat {
    server 192.168.10.101:8443;
    server 192.168.10.102:8443;
    keepalive 16;
}
server {
listen       443 ssl;
#server_name  192.168.10.100;
server_name myserver.home.net;

ssl_certificate      /opt/mount/config/certs/test_ssl.pem;
ssl_certificate_key  /opt/mount/config/certs/test_ssl_cert.key;

ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
ssl_session_timeout  5m;

ssl_ciphers RC4:HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
keepalive_timeout 180s;


location / {
    proxy_pass             https://tomcat/mydashboard/;
    proxy_set_header       X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header       Host $http_host;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    chunked_transfer_encoding off;
    proxy_cookie_domain     ~(.*)$  ws1.home.net;
    rewrite ^/dashboard/(.*)$ /$1 last;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

For anyone stuck with this issue add the following to the location section.

```
 proxy_read_timeout 7200;
```

Comment: Hm, you have connections your server needs up to 2 hours to respond to?